# Issue with $(this) in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I have the following:

```
$(".views").click(function() {
    $(this).(".views").show();

});

$(".closeviews").click(function () {
    $(this).(".closeviews").hide();

});
```

This will open up a list based on which view list they want to look at,  for some reason it's telling me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

Once I remove the `(this).`  it goes away, so I am kinda confused as to why it is telling me that.

EDIT:

I changed to this:

```
$(".views").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".views").show()

});

$(".closeviews").click(function () {
    $(this).find(".closeviews").hide()

});
```

Does nothing, if I go to the view list above it opens this one and that one.

UDATE:

HTML:

The one I am trying to open with the above script -

```
<input type='button' value='View Your Employees' class='views' name='views' /> 
<input type='button' value='Close' class='closeviews' name='closeviews' />
```

The one I click above this one, opens the above plus this one:

Script:

```
$(".notempl").click(function () {
    $(".notempltable").show();

});

$(".closenotempl").click(function () {
    $(".notempltable").hide();

});
```

HTML:

```
<input type='button' value='View Employees' class='notempl' name='notempl' /> 
<input type='button' value='Close' class='closenotempl' name='closenotempl' />
```

UPDATE:

Hey guys thanks for all the help, got it sorted out.  I actually was telling the wrong thing to show and hide.  Each list is populated by a PDO statement and a table so I needed to show the table, hide the table not the button.

Thanks guys :)

Comment: I don't think there's any need for a subsequent DOM lookup at all.

Comment: You have prentheses immediately after periods.  Not a good idea...

Comment: All yours brother. hey question though what about for each table if I rename each table the same name how would I use or where would I put $(this) at to show and hide it?

Comment: @David Well if all of the tables are named after the button with the word 'table' appended, you can make one handler for all the buttons and say `$('.' + this.className + 'table')`. Is that what you mean? OR...if all the tables have the *same* class name, but are right under their buttons in the DOM markup, you can use [`$(this).next('.tableClassNameHere')`](http://api.jquery.com/next). Depends on the relative layout of your tables to your buttons

Comment: `$(".tablelist").show()` is what I want to use `this` on...so If I have mutiple tables name .tablelist, I want the one related to the button pressed to open.

Comment: Right, but `".tablelist"` matches all of them, so that's why I say you can try using `this` with `.next` or [`.prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev) (as shown above). Also note that an element can have more than one class name (space separated), so they can have one in common as well as distinct ones related to the buttons. There are other ways of doing DOM searching to find the correct table, see the [various jQuery DOM traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/). You can also try `$('.tablelist').filter('.' + this.className )` if you end up giving the table both classes.

Comment: the .next does not work.

Comment: `$(".views").click(function() {
 $(this).next('.tablelist').show(); 
 
});`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22945/discussion-between-david-biga-and-nbrooks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/J42yk/)

HTML:

```
<ul class='viewstable'>
  <li>Sample</li>
  <li>Sample 2</li>
</ul>

<input type='button' value='View Your Employees' class='views' name='views' /> 
<input type='button' value='Close' class='closeviews' name='closeviews' />
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
  $(".views").click(function () {
    $('.viewstable').show();
  });

  $(".closeviews").click(function () {
    $('.viewstable').hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

It should be

```
$(this).hide();
$(this).show();
```

If you remove the $(this) then it will hide and show all the elements with that class. If you click on any of them then all of them will be hidden. I do not believe you want that.

Comment: The code works, but the description is strange. Your code shows that you are trying to show an element that you have to click on to show. This means that it has to be visible to click, and you make it visible after the click. I just showed you the correct way to use $(this) because you put in so little code I cannot help you any further. The best answer you will get if you show us the html code, go make a http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean `$(this).find(".views").show()`

Comment: @David `this` is already a `.views` element by virtue of being in the context of the `click` handler. Thus it isn't necessary to do any further DOM searching (using `.find`); simply call `$(this).hide()` etc.

Comment: I did, does not work. if I click the above list it opens the one I want open plus the top one I clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to find the same class.  As you can just do $(this) to access the class and its done:

```
$(".views").click(function() {
    $(".closeviews").show(); //Show close 
});

$(".closeviews").click(function () {
    $(".views").hide(); // Hide view
});
```

Comment: May be i missed something.

Comment: I read the question but couldnt understand it properly.  Can you explain it

Comment: So for instance, I have 1 and 2.  2 I want to open but if  I click 2 it does not open.  If I click 1, 2 and 1 open.

Comment: what is 1 and 2 here ?  Can you be more specific ?